# Prove {$x|P(x) \land S(x)$}$ \cup $ {$x|P(x) \land \neg S(x)$} $= ${$x|P(x)$}

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, proof-writing

So far, I have only expanded the left hand side to

[ {$x|P(x)$}$\cap ${$x|S(x)$} ]   $\cup $  [ {$x|P(x)$ }$\cap ${$x|\neg S(x)$} ]

and I'm not sure what to do next.

Comment: Note that $(P(x)\wedge S(x))\wedge (P(x)\wedge \neg S(x)) \equiv P(x)\wedge (S(x)\vee \neg S(x))$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually push toward the logic rather than pull the logic out toward the sets.  Often by definition we have $$\{ x\ |\ P(x) \}\cup\{ x\ |\ Q(x) \} = \{ x\ |\ P(x)\lor Q(x)\}$$

So your problem reduces to $$\{ x\ |\ (P(x)\land S(x))\lor(P(x)\land\lnot S(x)) \}$$ and thus checking that $$(P(x)\land S(x))\lor(P(x) \land \lnot S(x)) \Leftrightarrow P(x)$$

To do this, we just undistribute the $P(x)$ so the problem becomes
$$P(x)\land(S(x)\lor\lnot S(x)) \Leftrightarrow P(x)$$

We have, by the law of excluded middle, $Q\lor\lnot Q \Leftrightarrow \top$ for all $Q$ which would complete the proof.

This also indicates that this statement is not generally true in constructive logic where the law of excluded middle doesn't necessarily hold. In that case, $\{ x\ |\ P(x) \}$ may contain elements for which neither $S(x)$ nor $\lnot S(x)$ are provable, making it different from $\{ x\ |\ P(x)\land(S(x)\lor\lnot S(x))\}$.

Answer (score 0):

[ {$x|P(x)$}$\cap ${$x|S(x)$} ]   $\cup $  [ {$x|P(x)$ }$\cap ${$x|\neg S(x)$} ]
$$$$ 
= {$x|P(x)$} $\cap $ [ {$x|S(x)$} $\cup $ {$x|\neg S(x)$} ] (Distributivity of OR over AND)

$$$$={$x|P(x)$} $\cap $ U
$$$$={$x|P(x)$}